# Processing associative array and outputting results

Tags: php

Ive got an associative array thats pulled from mysql results and id like to display results from the array. For some reason its just not printing the results. this is a var_dump of the associative array:

```
array(7) { 
 ["id"]=>  string(3) "143"
 ["url"]=>  string(61) "http://news.bbc.co.uk/sport1/hi/football/eng_prem/9013345.stm"
 ["title"]=>  string(78) "BBC Sport - Football - Sir Alex Ferguson warns Man Utd ahead of Liverpool game"
 ["excerpt"]=>  string(138) "Carelessness must stop - Ferguson: Manchester United boss Sir Alex Ferguson warns his players to cut out the error... http://bbc.in/9tDv0R"
 ["tweet_count"]=> string(3) "183"
 ["created_at"]=> string(10) "2010-09-19" 
 ["media_type"]=> string(4) "news" 
}
```

and this the code im using to TRY to process it:

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($search))
      {

         foreach($row as $key=>$value)
            {
               echo $value["title"]."<br/>";
            }
         }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With mysql_fetch_assoc you have one complete row in $row variable.

Then you're doing foreach on this variable, where keys are: "id", "url", "title" (and others), and values are corresponding to these keys.

Instead of $value['title'] use $value

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($search))
{
  echo $row['id'].': '.$row['title'];
  foreach($row as $key=>$value)
  {
    echo $key.': '.$value."<br/>";
  }
}
```

Comment: that works fine to output the content but i want to use different elements from the arrays and apply formatting and so on to the result,for example just to display the title and the excerpt and link the title to the url. so i need a way to access the individual elements

Comment: You use column name as key for assoc array, as in example above

Comment: thank you using the $row['id'] and so on,im able to access each row's individual data as its processed

Answer (score 1):

You already have reached farthest end of the array. 
Try this:

```
  foreach($row as $key=>$value)
            {
               echo $value."<br/>";
            }
```

instead of

```
 foreach($row as $key=>$value)
            {
               echo $value["title"]."<br/>";
            }
```

Comment: i tried that initially and it prints the first character in every field of the array for instamce for the example array row i gave it prints 1hBC12n with linebreaks after each character

Comment: Are you sure you are not doing echo $value[0] instead of echo $value;

Answer (score 0):

How to get the array values you wanted

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($search))
{
  foreach($row as $value)
  {
    echo "Title: ".$value['title']."<br />";
    echo "Excerpt: ".$value['excerpt']."<br />";
    echo "Title w/ Link: <a href=".$value['url'].">".$value['title']."</a><br />";
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the help but i tried that already as well and it only outputs the first character of the field,like the answer just above

Comment: made one small change: foreach($row as $value)

Comment: just tested your code adjustment and it still prints the first character

Comment: echo "Row value array: <pre>".print_r($row,true)."</pre><br />"; // Use this line to see the array values as I don't understand what's going on with your code. Please display the results so we can better understand